# Can Jackson resolve Ids to Objects using Spring Data Repositories?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jackson2

Today I wanted to use Spring-Data-Web-Support inside a JSON-Object like this.

```java
@Entity
public class Player {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Team team;
}

@Entity
public class Team {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<Player> members;
}

@RestController
public class Controller{
    @PostMapping("/team/")
    public Team save(@Requestbody Team team) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a new team out of existing players. Therefore I used the following requestbody:

```
{
    "name": "PowerRangers",
    "members": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I have been expecting Jackson to resolve the Ids to the corresponding Players in the database. This does not seem to happen.

Could somebody please tell me how to make it work or show me a more elegant way to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to write some code. Jackson is a JSON mapper. It takes a JSON string, and transforms it to an object. It has no idea that you're using JPA, that there are repositories, that the numbers in the array are IDs of players, that it needs to call one of your repositories method to get the corresponding members, etc. You have tow write that code.

Comment: And BTW, what you receive is not a Team. What you receives is an object that has a name property of type String and a members property which is an array of numbers. That doesn't match with a Team. A Team doesn't have an array of numbers. Use a class that matches with the JSON you receive. Create an actual Team from the object you receive, by calling the appropriate repository methods to get the members from their IDs.

Comment: @JBNizet I would really like to make that happen in the background. Do you have any hint on where to start, when I try to implement that feature into Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify your RequestBody like below.

```
{
    "name": "PowerRangers",
    "members": [
        { "fisrstName" : "ABC",
          "lastName" : "XYZ",
          "id" : 1
        }, { ... }
    ]
}
```

Also You also need to introduce @JsonBackReference/@JsonManagedReference on Entities to remove bidirectional flow.

Comment: This is the way I don't want to go. The players are already persistent objects, there is no need to send their complete structure to the backend.

Comment: what you will say in case of retrieving ?